# How to get the execution result of a stored procedure

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2008

I want to capture the execution result in a variable. If the procedure fails due to a deadlock or error how do I capture it programmatically.

The scenario is I have a SSIS package where I call a stored procedure. Now the stored procedure sometimes fails due to a deadlock but the package execution is logged as success.

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SP_NAME", sqlConn);
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 3500;
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The stored procedure doesn't take or return any variable. How do I determine here if the stored procedure executed successfully or had a failure.

Comment: That's not the behaviour I've observed. Where do you see package success? in the package logs or in SQL Agent? It appears you're calling it in script rather than an execute SQL task. Perhaps you are catching the error and ignoring it,

Comment: The success is shown in the SQL Agent. Yes I am calling it using a 'Script Task'. If an error happens while executing the SP will the status be thrown here?

Comment: Is there any way to capture the return code of the stored procedure here?

Comment: If you change ExecuteNonQuery() to ExecuteScalar() you can capture the return code of the stored procedure.

Comment: I always use an execute SQL task to execute a stored procedure and capture its output. There would be a lot more code in your script task perhaps you should post it all